# Breaking data into multiple display columns with Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

Overlap in terminology makes search for answers difficult for this one.

I'm looking for advice on the best way to implement a multiple-column display of my QuerySet that fills each column top to bottom over X columns. Meaning that the number of items in each column equals the QuerySet count divided by X (number of columns).

Using Offset doesn't work for this because I would like my data to grow into 4 columns without updating the offset manually. CSS floats work visually, but leave the data out of order.

Answer (score 7):

Something like that should work for you, pass the number of columns as `columns` to the template:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if forloop.first %}<div style="float:left;">{% endif %}
    {{ item }}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:columns %}
        </div><div style="float:left">
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %}</div>{% endif %}    
{% endfor %}
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: One tiny note, the divisibleby is misspelled in the code above, for those of us who cut and paste :)

Comment: @TechTeacherGirl: Thanks, I fixed it.  There's a good reason we don't have spell checkers in IDEs though.  ;)

Comment: This will work if instead of columns you actually pass the number of rows in a column, that you can precalculate in the view by dividing the total number of items to the number of columns as Kim said.

Comment: Has the problem that if the length of "items" is an exact multiple of "columns", you'll get a blank div. instead, put the "if forloop.counter" after the "if forloop.last" as an "elif"

Answer (score 1):

It seems like lazerscience's answer is on the right track - but I think the OP wants the data to alphabetically sort the data down the column and then start back at the top of the next column.  Using divisibleby: works to break the line after 'X' items, but I think it'll take a more complex template to do what the OP wants.

Not sure if it's possible, but in the view could you: Get item count, divide by 'columns' and used that # in Divisibleby to break into the next DIV column (the visual flow will be CSS)

As Lazers's example is now you're constructing Rows and then breaking it into columns, leaving the sort order across and then down.

Sorry if I missed something.

-K

Comment: My Example sorts the items down the columns, and THEN start the next column, it would firstly construct a row f you would put every single item into its own floating div!

Comment: I see, you are correct.  But you are still defining how many items are in the column, not how many columns their are. For display use, this isn't very useful, as a list grows from 10 to 200 items, the column count gets absurd unless you manually update the divisibleby:#. Instead, it would be useful to say I can fit 3 columns in my design, split the dataset into three chunks (1-10, 11-20, 21-30 for a 30 item list) and calculate the count of each column on the fly (1/3rd of the query set)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better go and use a jQuery plugin to make some columns from a  list.
[Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) works very well for me

Answer (score 0):

Here are some django template filter that split a list into multiple sub-lists:

[list partition template filters at djangosnippets.org](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/401/)

You could use these in a django template to split a long list into multiple columns as follows:

```
{% load list_tags %}
<h2>Some List</h2>

{% for sub_list in full_list|rows:"3" %}
<ul>
  {% for item in sub_list %}
    <li>
        {{item.name}}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I included the template filters in my project in a file called list_tags.py. Adjust the `{% load %}` tag as necessary.