# django separate texfield in some blocks at template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model like this

```
def mymodel(models.Model):
  thetext   = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

the content at admin is with a tinymce field

how can I put the content for render at template like 3 columns, for example, I think do with paragraphs but I would like use some tag separator to show the content between 2 tags like a column

some idea?

Comment: This snippet should give you some idea: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/401/ also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851734/breaking-data-into-multiple-display-colums-with-django

Comment: but the variable "thetext" is a texfield I want somethink like php strpos

Comment: what about markup ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/markup/ it has been deprecated in 1.5, but you can make it working .

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16692506/1257185

Comment: Solved! with self.contenido.split("tag-to-split") at model.py

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved with adding at model this method:

```
def thetext_in_col(self):
  return self.thetext.split("tag-to-split")
```

where "tag-to-split" is a tag in the content that split thetext variable in array